# Way to create Collections and retrieve data in a mongoDB running on Container

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, junit5, testcontainers

I have a MongoDB image running on a container in my application.
**I would like to create collections and documents on this DB and suddenly retrieve data to test a custom repository doing CRUD operations.**  ​
I'm new to JUnit tests and containers, so I really don't know how could I do this.
I've seen on the web that some people uses docker-compose file but I've created the MongoDBContainer directly with a Java class like the example below:

```
public class MongoDbContainer extends GenericContainer<MongoDbContainer> {

    
    public static final int MONGODB_PORT = 27018;
    public static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE_AND_TAG = "mongo:4.2";

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link MongoDbContainer} with the {@value DEFAULT_IMAGE_AND_TAG} image.
     * @deprecated use {@link MongoDbContainer(DockerImageName)} instead
     */
    @Deprecated
    public MongoDbContainer() {
        this(DEFAULT_IMAGE_AND_TAG);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link MongoDbContainer} with the given {@code 'image'}.
     *
     * @param image the image (e.g. {@value DEFAULT_IMAGE_AND_TAG}) to use
     * @deprecated use {@link MongoDbContainer(DockerImageName)} instead
     */
    public MongoDbContainer( String image) {
        this(DockerImageName.parse(image));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link MongoDbContainer} with the specified image.
     */
    public MongoDbContainer(final DockerImageName dockerImageName) {
        super(dockerImageName);
        addExposedPort(MONGODB_PORT);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the actual public port of the internal MongoDB port ({@value MONGODB_PORT}).
     *
     * @return the public port of this container
     * @see #getMappedPort(int)
     */
    public Integer getPort() {
        return getMappedPort(MONGODB_PORT);
    }

}
```

Then I use this class to create a new object in a test class like this below:

```
    @Testcontainers
    @SpringBootTest
    public class MongoDbContainerTest { 
    
        @Container
        static MongoDbContainer container = new MongoDbContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.2"));

        @Test
        public void Container_Should_Be_Up() {
           assertNotNull(container);
           assertNotNull(container.getExposedPorts());      
        }
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to run a docker container in test but I would like to know how to connect to this Database with Java code.

Thank you to anyone answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a *possible* (and recommended) way to create a MongoDB database with Testconainers.

You can even get rid of your custom `MongoDbContainer` class, as Testcontainers comes with a [dedicated Mongo module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There are multiple ways on how to override the connection string for your test, and `@DynamicPropertySource` is one of the most convenient:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
class CustomerRepositoryTest {
 
  @Container
  static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.4.2");
 
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);
  }

}
```

For more detailed information, see this [MongoDB Testcontainers Setup for @DataMongoTest](https://rieckpil.de/mongodb-testcontainers-setup-for-datamongotest/) article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Do you know how could I suddenly create collections and insert data into these only when I run tests?

Comment: If you're using [Spring Data MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference), you can insert data with any repository class and if you need low-level MongoDB access, inject the `MongoClient` to your test and perform any setup tasks